# Compare data within a table

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with data related to emergency incidents.  I'm looking to compare how many incidents overlap (by time).  I know that database is inherently unordered, but I have the incident start (and end) time, so I can order the records by time.

I think the final result would be a result set that had each record and an extra field that indicated whether it overlapped any incidents (0 for none, 1 for one overlap, 2 for two overlaps...).  Historically there is a finite number of overlaps (6 is the current max), but it would be possible to have more.

Currently, I do this type of analysis in Excel, with a helper column that compares the current record with previous records to determine if there's an overlap (or how many) and it works ok, but it seems like I should be able to accomplish this strictly within SQL.

EDIT:  Here's a sample from Excel, but the data is held in a single, SQL table.  I have admin priveleges for the database, so I can implement just about any solution-except changing the database structure (its a COTS system).  I've included the formula for the overlap column.  Also, I stopped the sample formula at 2 overlaps, but I'll account for more when I implment the answer.

```
Incident    Start               End          Overlap    Overlap Formula
    1   2012-01-01 07:00    2012-01-01 08:00        
    2   2012-01-02 07:00    2012-01-02 08:00    0   =IF(C2>B3,1,0)
    3   2012-01-02 07:30    2012-01-02 08:30    1   =IF(C3>B4,IF(C2>B4,2,1),0)
    4   2012-01-03 07:00    2012-01-03 08:00    0   =IF(C4>B5,IF(C3>B5,2,1),0)
    5   2012-01-04 07:00    2012-01-04 08:00    0   =IF(C5>B6,IF(C4>B6,2,1),0)
    6   2012-01-04 07:30    2012-01-04 08:30    1   =IF(C6>B7,IF(C5>B7,2,1),0)
    7   2012-01-04 07:45    2012-01-04 08:45    2   =IF(C7>B8,IF(C6>B8,2,1),0)
    8   2012-01-04 08:45    2012-01-04 09:45    0   =IF(C8>B9,IF(C7>B9,2,1),0)
    9   2012-01-05 07:00    2012-01-05 08:00    0   =IF(C9>B10,IF(C8>B10,2,1),0)
```

Comment: Can you show a few rows of sample data and desired results? Then we can construct a useful answer instead of guessing at schema/data and giving you queries with table and column names like foo and bar. Also posting your Excel function might be useful to see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I'm away from my desk now, but will add some data when I get back. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your questiion, and assuming a simple table for your incidents with columns `Id`, `StartDate`, and `EndDate` you could find the number of overlaps for each incident using a subquery with `APPLY`, something like:

```
SELECT I.Id, O.Overlaps
FROM Incidents I
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Overlaps
    FROM Incidents C
    WHERE C.Id <> I.Id
    AND  (C.StartDate BETWEEN I.StartDate AND I.EndDate OR
          C.EndDate BETWEEN I.StartDate AND I.EndDate)
) O
```

Comment: This worked great-thanks!  I'll have to look closer at the Subquery with Apply function-I'm not sure I understand entirely how it works, but it gave me the correct answer.

Comment: No problem!  APPLY is pretty handy; it gives you a way to execute a table valued function for every row of your main query.  So here, the query that figures out the overlap count gets applied to each row in the incidents table.  It's like a more flexable/powerful JOIN

Answer (score 1):

My english is very bad, so I don't completely understand your problem

if it's what I think, you can use group by in sql
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

```
select incident, count(*)
from your table
group by incident
```

also, if you have the dates, you can specify this query to a range of dates

```
select incident, count(*)
from your table
where startDate >= @startDate  and endDate <= @finishDate
group by incident
```

only if you want to do this between two dates

sorry for the bad english, and sorry if this is not what you want!